# Calling function inside if condition is synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

i have a method :

```
function checkNestedfield(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/ ) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}
```

while calling inside if condition getting me correct result but how should i know whether it will execute correctly every time.
So calling function inside if condition is async or sync process?

for eg:

```
if (checkNestedfield(someObj, 'stringValue')) {
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

Comment: It's synchronous and will be called every time, otherwise it won't know whether to execute the *else* block or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm a bit confused: what about this code suggests that it wouldn't be entirely synchronous? What is the code supposed to accomplish and how are you defining "correctness" here?

Comment: some people actually mix up what synchronous and asynchronous code is

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`try/catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch) logic in order to 'catch' if the function return some error or not, as show next:

```
let nestedField = false;

function checkNestedfield(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/ ) {
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      throw "myException"; // Give control to the 'catch' sentence
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}

try (
  checkNestedfield(someObj, 'stringValue');
) catch (e) {
  console.log('Log the error here');
}
```

This way if your `checkNestedfield` function fails, you could handle the error in whatever way you want. This behavior es always synchronous and will be called every time.

Hope this helps.